# Writing an openshift extension

Tags: go, openshift-origin, godeps

Trying to understand how one builds a tool consuming the Openshift Origin and Kubernetes APIs (I'm new to Go). It seems that I have a version of Kubernetes installed from Openshift and another version installed by `godep` and I'm getting all sorts of exciting version mismatches.

Here's my code so far:

```
package main

import (
    kclient "k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/unversioned"
    client "github.com/openshift/origin/pkg/client"
)

func main() {
    config := kclient.Config{
        Host: "...",
    }

    client.SetOpenShiftDefaults(&config)
    client := client.NewOrDie(&config)
}
```

I then did a `go get github.com/openshift/origin` which I can see has a copy of Kubernetes in it's `Godeps/_workspace/src` directory.

However when I do a `godep save` I get:

```
godep: Package (k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/client/unversioned) not found
```

If I do a `go get` to install Kubernetes I get a version that doesn't match with the version used by Openshift. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Just guessing here, but: Try a `godep restore` with the `github.com/openshift/origin` package, which should install the packaged Kubernetes to your `GOPATH`. Then a `godep save` in your package.

Comment: I discovered for the moment I can `export GOPATH=$GOPATH:${godep path}` which is letting me get the job done.